# \" is converted to \\" while saving the string to dictionary in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need to save string having " ' " in a dictionary along with \" instead of '.

the example is shown below. 
code:

```
 ss = "{'userName': {'suffix': None}"
   print ss
   print ss.replace("'", '\\"')
   temp = dict()
   temp["key"] = ss.replace("'", '\\"')
   print str(temp)
```

output:

```
{'userName': {'suffix': None}
{\"userName\": {\"suffix\": None}
{'key': '{\\"userName\\": {\\"suffix\\": None}'}
```

please let me know any one have any solution or alternative for this.

Comment: It's not converted. When you print a dict, you print its `repr`, which is further escaped for display purposes. Just print the actual string.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking at the `repr()` representation of a string. This is normal. A string representation uses escape codes for non-printable characters or anything that requires escaping.

Python containers show their contents, when printed, as string representations for debugging purposes. The resulting string representation is re-usable as a string literal, you can paste that right back into Python and it'll produce the *same value*.

Print individual values of you want to see the output unescaped:

```
print temp["key"]
```

and if you feel so inclined, compare that with the `repr()` result of the string:

```
print repr(temp["key"])
```